# mlr: why does reproducibility of hyperparameter tuning fail using parallelization?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mlr, reproducible-research

I use code based on Quickstart example in `mlr` [cheatsheet](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/raw/master/inst/cheatsheet/MlrCheatsheet.pdf). I added parallelization and tried to tune parameters several times.

**Question:** Why does reproducibility fail (why aren't the results identical) even if I set `set.seed()` every time before tuning? What is missing in my code? How should I modify the code to achieve reproducibility?

The code (on my PC it runs up to 1 min.):

```r
library(mlr)
#> Loading required package: ParamHelpers
library(parallel)
library(parallelMap)

# Load data
data(Soybean, package = "mlbench") 

# Initialize paralelllization
parallelStartSocket(cpus = 2)
#> Starting parallelization in mode=socket with cpus=2.

# Prepare data, task, learner
soy = createDummyFeatures(Soybean, target = "Class")
tsk = makeClassifTask(data = soy, target = "Class")
ho = makeResampleInstance("Holdout", tsk)
tsk.train = subsetTask(tsk, ho$train.inds[[1]])

lrn = makeLearner("classif.xgboost", nrounds = 10)
#> Warning in makeParam(id = id, type = "numeric", learner.param = TRUE, lower = lower, : NA used as a default value for learner parameter missing.
#> ParamHelpers uses NA as a special value for dependent parameters.

# Prepare for hyperparametar tuning
ps = makeParamSet(makeNumericParam("eta", 0, 1))
tc = makeTuneControlMBO(budget = 1)

# Turn off excessive output
configureMlr(show.info = FALSE, show.learner.output = FALSE)

# Tune parameters
suppressMessages({

    # set.seed(123456, "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
    clusterSetRNGStream(iseed = 123456)
    tr1  = tuneParams(lrn, tsk.train, cv2, acc, ps, tc)

    # set.seed(123456, "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
    clusterSetRNGStream(iseed = 123456)
    tr2  = tuneParams(lrn, tsk.train, cv2, acc, ps, tc)

})

# Stop paralellization
parallelStop()
#> Stopped parallelization. All cleaned up.
```

The results are not identical:

```r
all.equal(tr1, tr2)
#>  [1] "Component \"x\": Component \"eta\": Mean relative difference: 0.1849302"                                                                                                             
#>  [2] "Component \"y\": Mean relative difference: 1.074668e-05"                                                                                                                             
#>  [3] "Component \"resampling\": Component \"train.inds\": Component 1: Numeric: lengths (228, 227) differ"                                                                                 
#>  [4] "Component \"resampling\": Component \"train.inds\": Component 2: Numeric: lengths (227, 228) differ"                                                                                 
#>  [5] "Component \"resampling\": Component \"test.inds\": Component 1: Numeric: lengths (227, 228) differ"                                                                                  
#>  [6] "Component \"resampling\": Component \"test.inds\": Component 2: Numeric: lengths (228, 227) differ"                                                                                  
#>  [7] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"x\": Component \"eta\": Mean relative difference: 0.1849302"                                                                                   
#>  [8] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"y\": Mean relative difference: 1.074668e-05"                                                                                                   
#>  [9] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"opt.path\": Component \"env\": Component \"exec.time\": Mean relative difference: 0.1548913"                                                   
#> [10] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"opt.path\": Component \"env\": Component \"path\": Component \"eta\": Mean relative difference: 0.773126"                                      
#> [11] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"opt.path\": Component \"env\": Component \"path\": Component \"y\": Mean relative difference: 0.03411588"                                      
#> [12] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"final.opt.state\": Component \"loop.starttime\": Mean absolute difference: 1.810968"                                                           
#> [13] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"final.opt.state\": Component \"opt.path\": Component \"env\": Component \"exec.time\": Mean relative difference: 0.1548913"                    
#> [14] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"final.opt.state\": Component \"opt.path\": Component \"env\": Component \"path\": Component \"eta\": Mean relative difference: 0.773126"       
#> [15] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"final.opt.state\": Component \"opt.path\": Component \"env\": Component \"path\": Component \"y\": Mean relative difference: 0.03411588"       
#> [16] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"final.opt.state\": Component \"opt.problem\": Component \"design\": Component \"eta\": Mean relative difference: 0.773126"                     
#> [17] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"final.opt.state\": Component \"opt.result\": Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"x\": Component \"eta\": Mean relative difference: 0.1849302"
#> [18] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"final.opt.state\": Component \"opt.result\": Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"y\": Mean relative difference: 1.074668e-05"                
#> [19] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"final.opt.state\": Component \"random.seed\": Mean relative difference: 1.28965"                                                               
#> [20] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"final.opt.state\": Component \"time.created\": Mean absolute difference: 5.489337"                                                             
#> [21] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"final.opt.state\": Component \"time.last.saved\": Mean absolute difference: 5.489337"                                                          
#> [22] "Component \"mbo.result\": Component \"final.opt.state\": Component \"time.used\": Mean relative difference: 0.6841712"
```

I also tried

```r
set.seed(123456, "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
```

instead of

```r
parallel::clusterSetRNGStream(iseed = 123456)
```

and this did not lead to reproducibility.

But when parallelization is turned off, the results are identical (with `set.seed(123456, "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")` (except beginning/end time and duration).

Comment: There are several issues at GH for this, eg https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/938. Does that help?

Comment: As written in that issue, I used `"L'Ecuyer-CMRG"` random number generator, and, as written in docentation of this generator, I used at least 6-digit integer number as seed.

Comment: Are there any good examples/tutorials how to use `mlr` with parallel computing from a to z (all pipeline of functions from task definition, to parameters tuning, to feature selection, to cross-validation for performance evaluation, to final model) and get reproducible results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code creates the same reproducible results (except the timings)

```
library(mlr)
library(parallel)
library(parallelMap)

# Load data
data(Soybean, package = "mlbench") 

# Initialize paralelllization
parallelStartSocket(cpus = 2)

# Prepare data, task, learner
soy = createDummyFeatures(Soybean, target = "Class")
tsk = makeClassifTask(data = soy, target = "Class")
ho = makeResampleInstance("Holdout", tsk)
tsk.train = subsetTask(tsk, ho$train.inds[[1]])

lrn = makeLearner("classif.xgboost", nrounds = 10)

# Prepare for hyperparametar tuning
ps = makeParamSet(makeNumericParam("eta", 0, 1))
tc = makeTuneControlMBO(budget = 1)

# Turn off excessive output
configureMlr(show.info = FALSE, show.learner.output = FALSE)

# Tune parameters
suppressMessages({

  set.seed(123456, "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
  clusterSetRNGStream(iseed = 123456)
  tr1  = tuneParams(lrn, tsk.train, cv2, acc, ps, tc)

  set.seed(123456, "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
  clusterSetRNGStream(iseed = 123456)
  tr2  = tuneParams(lrn, tsk.train, cv2, acc, ps, tc)

})

parallelStop()
```

What did I change?
I also set the local seed.
Why?
Because it's not only about the seeding on the parallel processes. Also the seeding on the main machine is important as it influences eg. the resampling (which is drawn on the master).

Comment: It seems that you only had to uncomment two rows in my code. But I did not have enough knowledge for this decision. Theoretically, is there a difference if I use `set.seed()` firstly and `clusterSetRNGStream()` secondly or vise versa?

Answer (score 2):

It does make a difference whether one uses parallelism based on forked processes (multi-core, not available on Windows) or on separate processes with socket communication. For multi-core parallelism, it is sufficient to set the seed and RNG kind **before** `parallelStart()` to get same random numbers with every call:

```
library(parallelMap)

suppressMessages({
    set.seed(123456, "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
    parallelStartMulticore(cpus = 2)
    r1 <- parallelMap(runif, rep(3, 2))
    parallelStop()

    set.seed(123456, "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
    parallelStartMulticore(cpus = 2)
    r2 <- parallelMap(runif, rep(3, 2))
    parallelStop()
})
all.equal(r1, r2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

For socket based parallelism we can make use of `parallel::clusterSetRNGStream()` **after** `parallelStart()` as mentioned in [GitHub issue](https://github.com/berndbischl/parallelMap/issues/31):

```
library(parallelMap)

suppressMessages({
    parallelStartSocket(cpus = 2)
    parallel::clusterSetRNGStream(iseed = 123456)
    r1 <- parallelMap(runif, rep(3, 2))
    parallelStop()

    parallelStartSocket(cpus = 2)
    parallel::clusterSetRNGStream(iseed = 123456)
    r2 <- parallelMap(runif, rep(3, 2))
    parallelStop()
})
all.equal(r1, r2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

This should also work with your real problem, although I have not tested it.

Comment: If I use `parallelMap()`, the results are reproducible, but in my example, I do not get reproducible results :(

Comment: Even this code gives reproducible results:
`library(parallelMap);

parallelStartSocket(cpus = 2);

parallel::clusterSetRNGStream(iseed = 123456);
r1 <- parallelMap(runif, rep(3, 2));

parallel::clusterSetRNGStream(iseed = 123456);
r2 <- parallelMap(runif, rep(3, 2));

parallelStop();
    
all.equal(r1, r2)` 
(restarting of paralellization removed).

Comment: @Vilmantas This is odd. Can you try with a simpler example that does not take 15 min using 7 cores?

Comment: I updated my question. Now the code runs up to 1 minute on my PC.

Comment: @Vilmantas I can reproduce the issue. What I find odd: if I run this sequentially, the result is equal for both runs but very different from the parallel run (eta=0.537 instead of 0.304 or 0.348). I have no idea how to debug this further.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/berndbischl/parallelMap/issues/57) in GitHub repository of `parallelMap`.